# MKS124814: Cannot show view information: View is unsupported in the Integration API

Tags: java, mks, mks-integrity

I want to get remote member(latest revision file) from MKS by passing filepath, servername and port  number. Finally I found below SI command

si viewrevision --revision=revision_number absoluthpathofmemberfileinsandbox

But I am getting exception when i run throw MKS JAVA API 
MKS124814: Cannot show view information: View is unsupported in the Integration API.

Please let me know how to resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `si projectco --nolock` command to download arbitrary members to a local file. You just need to know the project name, which you can easily retrieve from the sandbox by using `si sandboxinfo`.

```
>si sandboxinfo --sandbox=c:\your\sandbox\project.pj
[...]
Configuration Path: #/your/project/path/here
[...]

>si projectco --project=#/your/project/path/here --hostname=mks --port=7001 --targetFile=c:\temp\myfile.txt --nolock --revision=1.2.3.4 myfile.txt
```